# Composer failing update without a clear reason

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

I have the following in my `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^5.3",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.*@dev",
    "laravelangular/generators": "^3.0",
    "irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard": "^1.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.8.2",
    "jenssegers/mongodb": "^3.6",
    "ext-mongodb": "^1.4.0",
    "ext-fileinfo": "*",
    "spatie/laravel-fractal": "^3.4",
    "intervention/imagecache": "^2.3",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "wildside/userstamps": "^0.5.1",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.19.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "davidepastore/codice-fiscale": "^0.5.1",
    "league/csv": "^9.0",
    "thibaud-dauce/laravel-notifications-mattermost": "^1.0",
    "nztim/mailchimp": "^3.10"
}
```

When running `composer update` it says `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages`

Howerver the output does not help me in finding what's the issue:

```
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.40
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.47
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.46
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.45
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.43
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.42
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.40
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.39
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.3.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.2
    - Installation request for laravelangular/generators ^3.0 -> satisfiable by laravelangular/generators[3.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.1
    - jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.4 requires illuminate/events ^5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.0, v5.8.1, v5.8.10, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.13, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.16, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22, v5.8.23, v5.8.24, v5.8.25, v5.8.26, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.38, v5.8.4, v5.8.5, v5.8.6, v5.8.7, v5.8.8, v5.8.9], illuminate/events[v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
    - jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.3 requires illuminate/events ^5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.0, v5.8.1, v5.8.10, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.13, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.16, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22, v5.8.23, v5.8.24, v5.8.25, v5.8.26, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.38, v5.8.4, v5.8.5, v5.8.6, v5.8.7, v5.8.8, v5.8.9], illuminate/events[v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
    - jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.2 requires illuminate/events ^5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.0, v5.8.1, v5.8.10, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.13, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.16, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22, v5.8.23, v5.8.24, v5.8.25, v5.8.26, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.38, v5.8.4, v5.8.5, v5.8.6, v5.8.7, v5.8.8, v5.8.9], illuminate/events[v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
    - jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.1 requires illuminate/events ^5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.0, v5.8.1, v5.8.10, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.13, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.16, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22, v5.8.23, v5.8.24, v5.8.25, v5.8.26, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.38, v5.8.4, v5.8.5, v5.8.6, v5.8.7, v5.8.8, v5.8.9], illuminate/events[v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
    - jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.0 requires illuminate/events ^5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.0, v5.8.1, v5.8.10, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.13, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.16, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22, v5.8.23, v5.8.24, v5.8.25, v5.8.26, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.38, v5.8.4, v5.8.5, v5.8.6, v5.8.7, v5.8.8, v5.8.9], illuminate/events[v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.10.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.11.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.12.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.13.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.13.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.14.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.15.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.15.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.16.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.17.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.17.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.4.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.5.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^5.3 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.0, v5.3.1, v5.3.10, v5.3.11, v5.3.12, v5.3.13, v5.3.14, v5.3.15, v5.3.16, v5.3.17, v5.3.18, v5.3.19, v5.3.2, v5.3.20, v5.3.21, v5.3.22, v5.3.23, v5.3.24, v5.3.25, v5.3.26, v5.3.27, v5.3.28, v5.3.29, v5.3.3, v5.3.30, v5.3.31, v5.3.4, v5.3.5, v5.3.6, v5.3.7, v5.3.8, v5.3.9, v5.4.0, v5.4.1, v5.4.10, v5.4.11, v5.4.12, v5.4.13, v5.4.14, v5.4.15, v5.4.16, v5.4.17, v5.4.18, v5.4.19, v5.4.2, v5.4.20, v5.4.21, v5.4.22, v5.4.23, v5.4.24, v5.4.25, v5.4.26, v5.4.27, v5.4.28, v5.4.29, v5.4.3, v5.4.30, v5.4.31, v5.4.32, v5.4.33, v5.4.34, v5.4.35, v5.4.36, v5.4.4, v5.4.5, v5.4.6, v5.4.7, v5.4.8, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.1, v5.5.10, v5.5.11, v5.5.12, v5.5.13, v5.5.14, v5.5.15, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.18, v5.5.19, v5.5.2, v5.5.20, v5.5.21, v5.5.22, v5.5.23, v5.5.24, v5.5.25, v5.5.26, v5.5.27, v5.5.28, v5.5.29, v5.5.3, v5.5.30, v5.5.31, v5.5.32, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.38, v5.5.39, v5.5.4, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.42, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.5.45, v5.5.46, v5.5.47, v5.5.48, v5.5.49, v5.5.5, v5.5.6, v5.5.7, v5.5.8, v5.5.9, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.18, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.40, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.12, v5.7.13, v5.7.14, v5.7.15, v5.7.16, v5.7.17, v5.7.18, v5.7.19, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.24, v5.7.25, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.29, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.1, v5.8.10, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.13, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.16, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22, v5.8.23, v5.8.24, v5.8.25, v5.8.26, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.38, v5.8.4, v5.8.5, v5.8.6, v5.8.7, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb ^3.6 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.6.0, v3.6.1, v3.6.2, v3.6.3, v3.6.4].
```

It says "Conclusion: dont' install laravel/framework vXXX" but it provides zero information as to how it reached this conclusion.

The  only information it gives is stuff like:

> Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb ^3.6 -> **satisfiable** by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.6.0, v3.6.1, v3.6.2, v3.6.3, v3.6.4].

AFAIK satisfiable means "I can install these versions" so everything seems ok. There is zero mention of an unsatisfiable dependency.

So what is going on? Why does `composer update` fail?

Answer (score -1):

That's a problem of mixing incompatibel packages: `laravelangular/generators` requires Laravel up to 5.6 (even in the latest version of that generators package), `jenssegers/mongodb` with the version constraint `^3.6` requires Laravel 5.8 or 6.

Installing `jenssegers/mongodb` with the constraint `^3.5` might solve this problem, as it is compatible with Lavavel 5.6